# Using output of INDIRECT into VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm having no results and hours sailing through forums or webs arent being productive. I have a workbook that references 2 or three other workbooks to construct its tables. I did it manually the first time continuing my superior's work and changed every formula of every sheet in my document to reference sheets with the same name in those other documents. I thought it would we great if I could rethink or tweak the formula so that it automatically references the precise sheets it needs. First I run a macro that writes on cell K2 the name of the current sheet and ideally I would have a formula that composes that with the name of those other workbooks stored in other cells, in this case in the cell A20 of a sheet called Filtros. Using INDIRECT I managed to print into a cell the concatenation I want:

=INDIRECTO("Filtros!A20")&K2&"'!$B$2"

succesfully prints:

'c:\user\SD64868\Documents\TrabajoDavidSandoval\Mercados[Mercado_ene-sep.xlsx]ALM_PE'!$B$2

which is exactly what my vlookup needs

=BUSCARV($B2;'c:\user\SD64868\Documents\TrabajoDavidSandoval\Mercados[Mercado_ene-sep.xlsx]ALM_PE'!$B$2:$D$150;2;0)

but when I plug mi formula into the vlookup, errors, directly not working, problems with quotes...
I have tried everything, I've tried skipping the INDIRECT and directly concatenating the String needed as:

=Filtros!A20&K2

I've also tried all sort of positions for the quotes
Does anybody have an answer? Am I even understanding this correctly? is there anyway to plug into the lookup the text I'm getting from that Indirect?
Thank you

I didn't translate the names because INDIRECTO is INDIRECT and apart from that I just use BUSCARV which is VLOOKUP

I would also be fine if I could just take this

=BUSCARV($B2;'c:\user\SD64868\Documents\TrabajoDavidSandoval\Mercados[Mercado_ene-sep.xlsx]ALM_PE'!$B$2:$D$150;2;0)

and rework it to concatenate just the sheet from that cell but it doesn't work either:

=BUSCARV($B2;'c:\user\SD64868\Documents\TrabajoDavidSandoval\Mercados[Mercado_ene-sep.xlsx]&K2'!$B$2:$D$150;2;0)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, translate the functions names into English, the main language here on SO or people won't be able to help

Comment: You can't use a text address directly in a formula like that. You would need another INDIRECT function but that won't work with a closed workbook.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns Thank you but I considered that as I only use a couple of them, it was easy to understand and it also suggests that im using Spanish format

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the below?

English:

```
=VLOOKUP($B2, INDIRECT(Filtros!A20 & K2 & "!$B$2:$D$150"), 2, 0)
```

Spanish;

```
=BUSCARV($B2; INDIRECTO(Filtros!A20 & K2 & "!$B$2:$D$150"); 2; 0)
```

Comment: thank you very much but sadly this does not work, it throws REF error.

Comment: Just double check that if you put `=Filtros!A20 & K2 & "!$B$2:$D$150"` it outputs a valid address of the range that you want to reference? Also, per @Rory's comment on your question, it won't work if the other workbook isn't open.